# Property descriptors in ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

How do I translate the following code to an ES6 class:

```
var Mergesort = (function() {
    function Mergesort(){}
    Object.define(Mergesort.prototype,'readOnlyMethod',{
        value:function(){/*DO SOMETHING, RETURN SOME VAL*/},
        configurable:false,
        writable:false,
        enumerable:false
    });
    return Mergesort;
})()
```

Comment: Why not keep exactly that code?

Comment: That’s mostly a regular method, except for the `writable: false, configurable: false`. Do you really need that? (If so, it works exactly the same way with an ES6’s class’s `prototype` as with a function’s `prototype`.)

Comment: What have you tried and what Problems have you encountered?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `Object.defineProperty`?

Comment: Why are you down voting straight away?
what wrong with the question?
I'm searching how to translate this design pattern which is ES5 to the ES6 class syntax.
Whats the problem with question?

Comment: @TomasKatz This is not generally regarded as a "design pattern". Please explain your motivation for writing such uncommon ES5 code, so that we can suggest solution with `class` syntax that stays true to the idea.

Comment: Don’t be rude. Do understand the request for clarification, and answer it if you’d like a potentially more precise answer in turn.

Comment: 1) It is a design pattern for object creating in Javascript
2) It is a common practice to in ES5 to create a Frozen property (please reffer to the link I provided above)
3) ES6 class syntax provides a way to declare classes without the (function(){return Class })() syntax, thus fur the answer used this pattern.
4) The question is very legitimate on how to translate an ES5 design pattern to an ES6 class design pattern.

Comment: Okay, well, it looks like there’s a correct answer to that in the answer section right now.

Comment: What link? I don't see a link.

Comment: @connexo: Deleted comment, link was just https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 2):

The literal ES6 translation would be

```
const Mergesort = (() => {
    class Mergesort {}
    Object.defineProperty(Mergesort.prototype, 'readOnlyMethod', {
        value() { /*DO SOMETHING, RETURN SOME VAL*/ },
        configurable: false,
        writable: false,
        enumerable: false
    });
    return Mergesort;
})();
```

but assuming you want to define the method as part of the `class` expression, just change the property descriptor afterwards:

```
class Mergesort {
    readOnlyMethod() { /*DO SOMETHING, RETURN SOME VAL*/ }
}
Object.defineProperty(Mergesort.prototype, 'readOnlyMethod', {configurable:false, writable:false});
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea `defineProperty` did that when the property already exists.